# Suddenly I've got "Oops! That page can’t be found." on certain pages.

Tags: wordpress

**WORDPRESS**

In my services menu there are subpages there. here's the structure

exampleurlonly.com/services

```
Services
- Service 1
- Service 2
- service 3
- Service 4
```

under the Parent Menu Services all the subpages suddenly breaks. It turns out to be "not found"

I tried to fixed this by using these method:

**1.** I go to settings > permalinks then click I click the "default/plain" then save after I save, I click the "post-name" and click save. Unfortunately it doesn't work.

**2.** I checked the .htaccess file and I did not find odds or error inside the .htaccess.

This is what it look's like inside my .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

**The last part I did is changing the slug of services *"exampleurlonly.com/services"* to *"exampleurlonly.com/list-service"*.**

Why I'm having the problem with the word "services" slug? actually it is working (services slug) and then suddenly it won't work anymore

It's strange. In my website I have 5 parent menus **About**(About has also submenus), **Services**(Services has also submenus), **Careers**(Careers has also submenus), **News** and **Contact**. and the only problem is the Services because all the submenus are "not found".

I hope you can enligthen me with my problem.

Comment: Check by backup the .htaccess file and also set permalinks to plain, also check by deactivating plugins.

Comment: @mayank Yes I did it, except on the de-activating the plugins. is there any problem in the plugin that may cause the permalinks to break? Currently I'm using Yoast for the seo

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue as I did migrated my website and created another copy one website from another website.

**Solutions I tried**

1. Settings-> Permalink - take copy of what previously was there and then changed to default permalink setting
   And it works for me.
2. You have changed your URL’s permalink structure and haven’t redirected the old URL.
3. check If You don’t have file permissions.
4. plugin/theme change it sometime you can try to deactive and activate again.